# Protect an image without using a plugin

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to completely protect an image, not just right click protection which can be easily thwarted.

I tried editing the graphics folder permissions in cPanel but that made the image disappear.

Is there any other way to protect an image from being stolen that is completely foolproof.

> EDIT
>
> > I cannot watermark this image so I need another way.
>
> EDIT 2
>
> > I just combined the base64 dataURL and right click protection. So I'm pretty much covered except for screenshots which I'm not that worried about. If only it was possible to keep people from taking a screenshot like using some freaky DRM tricks or something.

Comment: No there is no full proof way. The client needs the image file to be able to view it, therefore as soon as the asset is sent to the client, they have access to it.

Comment: If the image loads on the page, someone can always find a way to download it (like grabbing from the network panel of the browser dev tools) or even just take a screenshot.

Comment: Your best bet is to watermark the image (on the server) so that it isn't all that great for them to download it. You can deter downloads (like drawing the image to a canvas using base64 data). As others have said, there is no way to prevent downloading images, after all - for users to even see the images on your website they have already downloaded the image.

Comment: @RobM. I don't know why I didn't think of using base64 dataURL thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done. You can use a few tricks to make it more difficult, but the truth is once you sent that image over the wire, the user will be able to save it, share it, etc.

Watermark your valuable images or publish low res versions of them.